# Angular2Fire not able to retrieve data

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I tried to integrate angular2 app with firebasedb. I followed [angular2Fire Github Documentaion](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2). Am using angular CLI, installed angular2Fire, imported

```
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database';
```

in `app.module` with

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(constants.firebase),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule])
```

This constants.firebase contains firebase configuration.

In my home page component

```
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';

 db: AngularFireDatabase;
 lists:FirebaseListObservable<any[]>
 lists=this.db.list('/users');
```

This returns something like this[image]

I even updated firebase rules to public. I tried finding solutions but nothing helps. Can anyone help me to solve this issue. I just trying to console log the result obtained.

Comment: You need to subscribe to observables so `lists.subscribe(res =>{//res should have your data here});` To be honest its hard to say what you are trying to achieve here your question is not really clear. From what you actually pasted in it looks absolutely fine to me.

Comment: thanks @Vic that saved my day. But the list can be easily rendered to html using *ngFor ="let ........ | async".

Comment: Yes that too but you didn't specify what you are trying to do

Comment: done and edited.